# Checking overlap of pandas intervals not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bounding-box

I have a pandas dataframe with `bbox` information, represented as coordinates `x0, y0, x1, y1`. My ultimate goal is to create performant code that checks whether different bboxes overlap or not, so this means relying on vectorized operations only.

One approach I've tried to make work is taking advantage of `pandas.Interval` and `pandas.Interval.overlaps`, but I've encountered odd errors that appear when I try to get the overlaps.

Here is the code:

```
ts = original_df.copy()
ts['x0_prev'], ts['x1_prev'] = ts.x0.shift(), ts.x1.shift()
ts['x_range'] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(ts.x0, ts.x1)
ts['x_range_prev'] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(ts.x0_prev, ts.x1_prev)
ts['x_range_prev_alternative'] = ts.x_range.shift(1)
```

which will create something like this

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|       x0 |       y0 |       x1 |       y1 |   x0_prev |   x1_prev | x_range                                  | x_range_prev                             | x_range_prev_alternative                 |
|----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------|
|  48.57   |  57.066  | 131.03   |  66.0773 |  nan      |  nan      | (48.56999969482422, 131.0296630859375]   | nan                                      | nan                                      |
| 134.929  |  56.9787 | 176.847  |  64.1567 |   48.57   |  131.03   | (134.9290771484375, 176.84664916992188]  | (48.56999969482422, 131.0296630859375]   | (48.56999969482422, 131.0296630859375]   |
| 181.431  |  57.0757 | 190.916  |  64.1567 |  134.929  |  176.847  | (181.43089294433594, 190.91555786132812] | (134.9290771484375, 176.84664916992188]  | (134.9290771484375, 176.84664916992188]  |
|  47.8716 | 226.302  |  88.0859 | 233.354  |  181.431  |  190.916  | (47.87158966064453, 88.08585357666016]   | (181.43089294433594, 190.91555786132812] | (181.43089294433594, 190.91555786132812] |
|  92.414  | 226.273  | 130.684  | 233.354  |   47.8716 |   88.0859 | (92.41399383544922, 130.6843719482422]   | (47.87158966064453, 88.08585357666016]   | (47.87158966064453, 88.08585357666016]   |
| 131.951  | 230.308  | 134.57   | 231.162  |   92.414  |  130.684  | (131.95118713378906, 134.5701904296875]  | (92.41399383544922, 130.6843719482422]   | (92.41399383544922, 130.6843719482422]   |
| 135.259  | 226.273  | 139.808  | 233.363  |  131.951  |  134.57   | (135.25889587402344, 139.80819702148438] | (131.95118713378906, 134.5701904296875]  | (131.95118713378906, 134.5701904296875]  |
|  48.3469 | 237.826  |  95.2755 | 246.691  |  135.259  |  139.808  | (48.346893310546875, 95.27548217773438]  | (135.25889587402344, 139.80819702148438] | (135.25889587402344, 139.80819702148438] |
| 100.3    | 237.796  | 107.595  | 244.877  |   48.3469 |   95.2755 | (100.29961395263672, 107.59452056884766] | (48.346893310546875, 95.27548217773438]  | (48.346893310546875, 95.27548217773438]  |
|  48.3381 | 248.985  |  97.7703 | 257.851  |  100.3    |  107.595  | (48.338096618652344, 97.770263671875]    | (100.29961395263672, 107.59452056884766] | (100.29961395263672, 107.59452056884766] |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

and here are the dtypes

```
x0                                           float64
y0                                           float64
x1                                           float64
y1                                           float64
x0_prev                                      float64
x1_prev                                      float64
x_range                     interval[float64, right]
x_range_prev                interval[float64, right]
x_range_prev_alternative    interval[float64, right]
dtype: object
```

I've been able to get the logic to work using apply, but that is slow on larger files.

```
ts['overlap'] = ts.apply(lambda x : x['x_range'].overlaps(x['x_range_prev']),axis=1)
```

Out of the following options none work, saying that `overlaps` cannot be done to a Series.

```
ts['overlap'] = ts.x_range.overlaps(ts.x_range_prev)
ts['overlap'] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(ts.x0, ts.x1).overlaps(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(ts.x0_prev, ts.x1_prev))
ts['overlap'] = pd.Interval(ts.x_range).overlaps(pd.Interval(ts.x_range_prev))
```

The from_arrays option gives a NotImplementedError.